# Why can't i access a (static) method or a property which in Global.asax from APP_CODE folder?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I can access the function in the `Global.asax` from `Asp.net` web pages(.aspx)

(i've added `ClassName="Global"` and mark my method as `static`)

i can't access the class `Global` it from my code in `APP_Code` folder?

why is it?? any workaround?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to right click the project and unload it, then edit the project file an add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project...>
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="App_Code\MyFile.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had added the app_code but in project file it was set to "Content Include" rather than "Compile Include".  I updated  to Compile and then the global variables were available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create static method in a class in your app_code folder. You can access static method every page in application.

By the way [global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is using for application level events..

Comment: thanks but this is not my question. my question is how can it be done. or why it can't be done.